# How to Solve Nullpointer exception in TestNG with dependsOnGroups

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, browser-automation

I am planning to implement dependsOnGroups and Groups concept of testNG in my POM selenium framework.
So I have created a POC with simple code and found nullpointer exception while run.

Code:

```
public class TestNGDependsOnMethodsExample {

@BeforeMethod (alwaysRun = true)
public void before(){
    System.out.println("Before Method ");
}


@Test(priority=0 , groups={"a"})
public void firstTest() 
{

    Assert.assertEquals("1","1");
    System.out.println("firstTest");
}

@Test(priority=1 , groups={"b"})
public void secondTest() 
{
    Assert.assertEquals("Pass","Pass1111");
    System.out.println("secondTest");
}

@Test(priority=2 , dependsOnGroups={"a","b"} ) 
public void thirdTest() {
    System.out.println("thirdTest");
}

@Test(priority=3, groups={"c"},alwaysRun = true)
public void fourthTest() {
    System.out.println("fourthTest");
}
```

}

Exception :

> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.testng.remote.strprotocol.TestResultMessage.(TestResultMessage.java:127)
>     at
>   org.testng.remote.strprotocol.TestResultMessage.(TestResultMessage.java:148)
>     at
>   org.testng.remote.strprotocol.RemoteTestListener1.onTestSkipped(RemoteTestListener1.java:78)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1788)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.runTestListeners(Invoker.java:1780)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1103)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.runWorkers(TestRunner.java:1147)   at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:749)     at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:600)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:317)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:312)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:274)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:223)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1039)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:964)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:900)    at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)

Comment: @DhavalAtri What version of TestNG are you working on?

Comment: I am using Maven.
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
   <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
   <version>6.9.10</version>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

By making a new project same code works fine without  no `NullPointerException`.
TestNg 6.9 & 6.9.9 having some issue i.e. `testng-failur.xml` is not generated properly. Or `testng-failur.xml` contains pass test methods.